# android code not working for sprite sheet

Tags: android, android-layout

Can any one sort the problem in the code..i.e "The constructor CCSprite(String) is not visible".All the required  imports have been imported, i have commented the error on the specified line where it is anoying me. thanks in advance

```
   public class Sprite extends CCLayer{
    CCSprite mSprite;    

     protected Sprite() {
        super();
        CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize();     
        mSprite =new CCSprite("sprite.png");//Error:The constructor CCSprite(String) is not visible
        mSprite.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(mSprite.getContentSize().width/2.0f, mSprite.getContentSize().height/2.0f));
        addChild(mSprite);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is telling you that the constructor you call here is not visible, i.e. it is private or has package visibility. Are you sure the source you looked at is the source you are calling?

Comment: Now how should i get rid of this mess.